# Start local AWS SAM API without authorizers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

Starting with [version 1.80.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/tag/v1.80.0) running `sam local start-api` uses authorizers configured in the template.

This makes quickly checking that APIs behave as expected more difficult as with my simple setup I have to pretend I'm a production users. Is there a way to tell SAM to run the API without authorizers when using `local`?

Neither [the PR that introduced it](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/pull/5005) nor [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-start-api.html) mention anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I had the same problem, but it turned out that the server `sam local start-api` spins up does not behave exactly like API Gateway in terms of the stages.

For example, if your deployed endpoint is `https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Prod/hello/`, locally you would need to remove the stage `Prod` and just call it like `http://localhost:3000/health`.